# Keep showing res/values-zh/strings.xml instead of res/values-en even when my phone's locale is English

Tags: android, localization

Have an issue that my application keep showing res/values-zh/strings.xml instead of res/values-en even when my phone's locale is English or any other undefined locale(language).

**Here is my main activity java class and it is showing English but we get the result on phone in Chinese**

[image]

**Here is default values strings**

[image: Here is default values strings]

Would be much appreciated if someone have any idea on this issue as i had following the android studio documentation and the localization is not working properly and i could not find out the reason for quite long time. Kindly let me know if further info needed, thanks !

Comment: Post your code as **text**, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Android do you use?
Is it Android N? Android N allows the user to configure a list of languages. If the first language is not supported, and the second is Chinese, then you will get Chinese UI (if Chinese strings are available, of course)

Comment: solved , root cause is there are default locale set on sharepref. Thanks for your info also